# Qt - simple QML application doesn't work

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have just this simple qml application, that should output background color, when is clicked. Actually it still outputs `undefined`.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 1400
    height: 800
    color: "#414141"

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {console.log(parent.color)}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly why but it looks like `ApplicationWindow` is not directly the parent of your `MouseArea`. You can check this by adding an `id` to your `ApplicationWindow` like `root` and then changing your `onClicked` event to this

```
onClicked: {
  console.log("MouseArea parent is: ", parent);
  console.log("root is: ", root);
}
```

I get this in the output which shows two different items

```
MouseArea parent is:  QQuickItem(0x101d369b0)
root is:  ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_7(0x101d35460)
```

To avoid this, just use `console.log(root.color)` instead of using `parent`

Comment: yes you are right, output is different,  but actually now if i change parent to id value, then settings new color has no effect (nothings happened after root.color = "#414141")

Comment: @Krab >  I noticed that the color changes as soon as you "move" the Window which must force an update or something. You might want to report a bug. In the meantime you could put a `Rectangle` filling the whole parent and change its color?

Comment: yeah it works now if i add root.update() after color change. I don't know if this is bug, maybe i must call it, thx anyway.